# Reloading .bashrc after setting variables -- shell script

Tags: 14.04, command-line, bash, scripts

I have a simple script that sets up a CVS repository (and other things) for work. The script has a function which *should* set up the repository, but it does not properly reload .bashrc. The code is as follows:

```
#!/bin/sh
setupCVS()
{
   echo '#Environment variables' >> ~/.bashrc
   echo 'export CVSROOT=:<server path>' >> ~/.bashrc
   source ~/.bashrc
   cvs login
   cvs co <directories>
}

<other code>
setupCVS
```

This will allow the user to run the script and immediately be able to log into cvs and download the code. The issue is that the script does not resource .bashrc. I have tried using

```
exec bash
```

and

```
. ~/.bashrc
```

but I still receive a terminal message saying CVSRoot not set when it reaches

```
cvs login
```

Any ideas?
I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 if that is necessary at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A couple of things:

- The default `.bashrc` does nothing if the shell isn't interactive:

  ```
  # If not running interactively, don't do anything
  case $- in
      *i*) ;;
        *) return;;
  esac
  ```
- Your script is using `/bin/sh`. Don't source `.bashrc`. Any bash-specific stuff could cause problems. And as steeldriver notes, `/bin/sh` doesn't have `source`:

  ```
  $ sh -c 'source ~/.bashrc'
  sh: 1: source: not found
  ```

Why not just `export` the variable in addition to adding to `.bashrc`?